# Python: How to decrese a global number?

Tags: python

When using a global in python i write:

```
global Example
Example = 5
```

I now want to know how I can decrese this number as

```
Example - 5
```

Seems to do nothing.

Comment: `Example = Example - 5`

Comment: Type this into the Python console and you will see that you are at least *partially* wrong: it *does* do "something". See the official documentation, [3.1 Using Python as a Calculator](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator). Then proceed to 3.2.

Comment: It is all working now thank you for the help. i didn't expect to get an answer so soon to be honest

Comment: i feel like this was too easy to solve...

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as this. Try this:

```
Example -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way try this.

```
Example -= 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

```
Example = Example - 5
```

This is my preferred method

```
Example -= 5
```

This also works